# Elasticsearch Nest C# -- ElasticProperty Analyzer causing dynamic mapping

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, mapping, nest

I am using ElasticProperty attributes to define my index type mapping. This works:

```
[ElasticProperty(Boost = 2)]
public string Title { get; set; }
[ElasticProperty(Index = FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed)]
public string ActivityType { get; set; }
```

I create my index and everything looks good (I'm just copying the affected props):

```
        "properties": {
           "activityType": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
           },
           "title": {
              "type": "string",
              "boost": 2
           }
        }
```

BUT, when I drop the mapping, change the Analyzer and reindex watch what happens:

```
[ElasticProperty(Boost = 2, Analyzer = "keyword")]
public string Title { get; set; }
[ElasticProperty(Index = FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed)]
public string ActivityType { get; set; }
```

Result:

```
       "properties": {
           "activityType": {
              "type": "string"
           },
           "title": {
              "type": "string"
           }
       }
```

Can someone explain what's happening here? It seems that adding the Analyzer parameter forces the mapping to be generated dynamically. Why?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that on your application startup you're calling the following:

```
private readonly IElasticClient _client;
//initialize _client
_client.Map<YourTypeHere>(m => m.MapFromAttributes());
```

That code will apply any new mapping that you have.

Comment: If no mapping exists I call the MapFromAttributes() method. Everything works fine until I add the 'Analyzer = ""' parameter.